# Can we make a cipher (chain) with AES hard to invert for all (except one) chosen keys to prevent MitM? (e.g. make it asymmetric)

Tags: aes, public-key, meet-in-the-middle-attack

In target app users are equivalent to adversaries. They are allowed to pick chosen keys. 
If we use standard AES (in ECB mode)
$$c = AES(m,k) $$
Every user $u$ gets a cipher $c_u$. Two users $u_1, u_2$ have the goal to find a suitable key $k_u$ which leads to a common message $m$ (any 128-bit number) with
$$m = AES^{-1}(c_{1},k_1) = AES^{-1}(c_{2},k_2)$$
For normal AES they (in mean) only need to check about $2^{64}$ keys each to find a common $m$.
I'm looking for a way to make this much harder while keeping the assigned ID's/cipher $c_u$ as short as possible.

---

To **generalize** we have an encryption $E$ using a cipher/ID $c_i$ and a forward encryption key $e_{i}$ resulting in a new $c_{i+1}$ and a backward decryption key $d_{i+1}$
$$E(c_i,e_{i}) \rightarrow (c_{i+1},d_{i+1})$$
Used at the decryption $D$ we always need to end where we started from (bijection).
$$D(c_{i+1},d_{i+1}) \rightarrow (c_{i},e_{i})$$
This also need to be the case if we start with $D$ and apply $E$ on the results as long the parameters chosen for $D$ are valid. We are allowed to reject them during the calculation of $D$. 
Encryption $E$ need to be calculated as fast as possible for many chosen keys $e$. This always results in valid $c_{i+1},d_{i+1}$. Rejection not allowed there.

To avoid meet-in-the-middle-attack finding valid $d_{j}$ for randomly chosen $c_j$ should be hard. According to my calculations in mean at least $2^{26}$ key trials for $D$ calculation are required.

However the app needs to find one valid key $d_j$ very fast to work as intended. Let's call this **spezial case key** $d_j^*$. Some trials are allowed but less than $2^{13}$ trials (assuming $E$ & $D$ similar calculation time). The less trials the better.
Furthermore this special key $d_j^*$ and every else valid $d_j$ should not give any hint about the key $e_{j-1}$ in forward direction. 
(In forward direction no such special case key $e_i^*$ need to be known or exist)

---

The app does use a **chain** of this encryption scheme with a length of (up to) $32$ instances and only allows $2^{16}$ different encryption keys $e_j$ on each step:
$$E(c_1,e_{1}) \rightarrow (c_{2},d_{2})$$
$$E(c_2,e_{2}) \rightarrow (c_{3},d_{3})$$
$$..$$
$$E(c_{31},e_{31}) \rightarrow (c_{32},d_{32})$$

Given two (random) $c_{32}$ (or any other index) we want to make it hard finding a common $c_1$.
As each $e_i$ only has $2^{16}$ choices it leaves $128-16 = 112$ bit space for things like key extension or modification which makes the inverse key hard to guess.
However the keys $e,d$ should only depend on their current $c$ and not on keys $e',d'$ or values $c'$ used before.

---

Assuming user count and effort is big enough finding a common $m$ for any two users is not a big problem as long it is slow enough. (Only two specifically chosen should be hard). If my calculations are correct target security of $\approx 2^{90}$ AES calculations would be sufficient.

---

Is there any common practice about this? Any idea how this can work?

---

**Trials:**

(**I**) *as alternative:* To get $2^{90}$ security we could also extend the $c_i$ with (at least) $2^{52}$ bit $c_{i,e}$ writing it as part of the key and applying a 2nd AES after a key modification. 
Encode function $E$ could look like this:
$$AES(c_i,[c_{i,e}, e_i] ) = c_i'$$
$$c_{i+1,e} = XOR(c_{i+1,e},c_i') \bmod 2^{26}$$
$$d_{i+1} = XOR(e_i,c_i') \bmod 2^{16}$$
$$AES(c_i',[c_{i+1,e}, d_{i+1}] ) = c_{i+1}$$
But this would increase the user cipher size/ID from 128-bit to 180-bit. Not a good option.

(**II**) To make the inverse harder and to get some special inverse key $d_j^*$ we could limit this extension $c_{i,e}$ to 16-bit and use it to calculate the spezial case.
$$AES(c_i,[c_{i,e}, e_i] ) = c_i'$$
$$c_{i+1,e} = XOR(c_{i+1,e},c_i') \bmod 2^{16}$$
$$d_{i+1} = XOR(e_i,c_i') \bmod 2^{16}$$
To make finding the inverse harder we can extend the key at the final step with $d_{i+1,e}$ using a invariant factor $a$
$$a = XOR(c_{i,e},e_i) = XOR(c_{i+1,e},d_{i+1})$$

$$d_{i+1,e} = a \cdot XOR(c_{i},c_i') \bmod 2^{42} $$
$$AES(c_i',[c_{i+1,e}, d_{i+1}, d_{i+1,e}] ) = c_{i+1}$$
If we pick a $d_{i+1}$ which leads to the factor $a = 0$ also $e_{i+1,e} = 0$ and we can quickly find one inverse. Finding others valid $d_{i+1}, d_{i+1,e}$ can get hard and requires some trials. $2^{42}$ can be increased to make it harder.  
However different values have different chances to get accepted and $d_{i+1}$ is not fully disentangled from $e_{i}$. (both share the same Xor value to their $c$ extension $c_{i,e}$ and $c_{i+1,e}$

(**III**) We can also make inverse harder by transforming the key during the forward direction $E(c_i,e_i)$ could look like this:
$$e_i' = Xor(e_i, [c_i]_{first 16 bit})$$
Take (at least) the last 26 bit of $c_i$ and determine the related prime number ignoring all primes smaller than $2^{16}$ $\rightarrow p_{c_i,last16bit}$ 
Compute decryption key $d_{i+1}$
$$d_{i+1} = e_i' \cdot p_{c_i,last26bit}$$
And use it for AES
$$AES(c_i,d_{i+1}) = c_{i+1}$$
In inverse direction we can determine $e_i$ and the last 26 bit of $c_i$ out of $d_{i+1}$.
It gets rejected if the last 26 bit are not equal to the resulting  $c_i$.
This approach's downside is it leaks some hints about $c_i$ and finding to correct primes can be a cumbersome.
Or the Cantor pairing function with a special case for $e_i'=0$:
$$d_{i+1} = \frac{(e_i' + c_{i,last26bit}) \cdot (e_i' + c_{i,last26bit}+1)}{2}+c_{i,last26bit}$$
Is there a nice formula without special case for $e_i'=0$?

---

Any better ideas?